# i need to open NBTedit

Tags: downloads, minecraft

I downloaded NBTedit so I could make a minecraft map look nicer, but I cannot open NBTedit, before I switched to ubuntu i NEVER had this problem, but I like ubuntu because its easer to navigate around and faster. please help!

Comment: Did it come in tar.gz format?

Comment: no, it came in .zip

Comment: Did you download the version for Windows?

Comment: it didnt specify what version it was

Comment: can you please [edit] your question and include the output of `unzip -l YOUR-ZIP-FILE`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you try to open **Windows** `exe` in Ubuntu.
Either install *Wine* (you can run `sudo apt-get install wine`) or reboot your computer to Windows, if you're running dual-boot.
Unfortunately there is no (at least not to my knowledge) native Ubuntu editor for Minecraft.